# CompletableFuture join() causing main thread hang

Tags: java, asynchronous, freeze, completable-future

I have two blocks of code that seem to be causing the main server thread to hang, but Im really not sure why it's hanging...

```
public static synchronized CompletableFuture<Void> saveAllToDatabase() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        for (UUID u : timeMap.keySet()) {
            saveUUIDToDatabase(u).join(); //This is PlaytimeManager:217
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized CompletableFuture<Void> saveUUIDToDatabase(UUID uuid) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        if (timeMap.get(uuid) == null) return;
        long l = getTime(uuid);
        long p = getPoints(uuid).join(); //This is PlaytimeManager:199
        Playtime.getData().save(uuid, l, p);
    });
}

public static CompletableFuture<Long> getPoints(UUID u) {
    Database d = Playtime.getData();
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        if (d.isSaved(u)) return getCachedPoints(u) == 0 ? d.getPlayer(u).getPoints() : getCachedPoints(u);
        return getCachedPoints(u);
    });
}
```

The `#join()` methods are causing the hanging, but they're wrapped in an async `CompletableFuture` so I'm unsure how exactly it's hanging...

The stack trace:
https://pastebin.com/5QhJPPhn

Comment: What is the returning type for `getPoints(uuid)` method?

Comment: It returns a `CompletableFuture<Long>`. Code updated in original post with the `getPoints` method

Comment: tried with minimum code and removed dependent modules, works fine for me     `public static synchronized CompletableFuture<Void> saveAllToDatabase() {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            for (UUID u : timeMap.keySet()) {
                saveUUIDToDatabase(u).join(); //This is PlaytimeManager:217
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: `public static synchronized CompletableFuture<Void> saveUUIDToDatabase(UUID uuid) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            long p = getPoints(uuid).join(); //This is PlaytimeManager:199
            System.out.println(uuid.toString() + ":" + p);
        });
    }`

Comment: `public static CompletableFuture<Long> getPoints(UUID u) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 10L);
    }`

Comment: Assumptions: `static Map<UUID, String> timeMap;

    static {
        timeMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        timeMap.putIfAbsent(UUID.randomUUID(), "b");
        timeMap.putIfAbsent(UUID.randomUUID(), "d");
        timeMap.putIfAbsent(UUID.randomUUID(), "f");
    }`

Comment: output: `66e9f22a-3933-47c7-a741-23186086695b:10
ec0bd92b-4ef4-4e2e-86b0-57abb6aa28f2:10
9be7e91b-3e8d-480c-8c8a-235599cfdad2:10`